# SQL filter according to two column

Tags: sql, group-by, selection, aggregation

**INPUT**

This is my table named 'MYTABLE'
The value of P3 are constant. But the value of P1 and P2 can be any integer!!!

[image]

**AIM**

My aim is to group by CITY AND PROD, for each city-prod combination and then (for each city-prod) take the smallest value of P3. **But I want to keep the values of P1 and P2 in the result.**

**QUERY**

So far I have tried the following query which does not provide the output I look for.

```
SELECT CITY, PROD, MIN(P3)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CITY, PROD
```

The result shows 2 row. 2 rows are correct but I loose P1 and P2 column.

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

So my question is how to write a query to keep the value of P1 and P2. (see image below)

[image]

PS: I am not absolutely looking to use 'GROUP BY' in my query. If there is another way to solve that it would be great too. Somehow I find the aim not too complex but for some reason I can't figure out (even after having looked on the internet) how to solve that.

Comment: So you want the max values of P1 and P2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a partition to select the proper row for each group of `city` and `prod`, based on the value of `p3`:

```
with cte as (select *, row_number() over(partition by city, prod order by p3) as rn
             from table1)
select city, prod, p1, p2, p3
from cte
where rn = 1
```

You can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d38b/6).

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for your query.  I will study this in details (I never used row_number() and I am not familiar with WITH....) However, it seems to work like a charm.

Comment: `row_number()` as I used it essentially adds an additional column, `rn`, that uniquely identifies rows in each sub-group (per `city` & `prod`) starting from 1. I sorted the sub-group by `p3`, and so I can safely drop every row except 1 -- that's what the `where` clause does.

Comment: Remove the `where` and add `rn` to the second `select` and you'll get exactly what I mean :)

Comment: Hello Blindy, I just discovered that the output is not what i expected if there is a null value and a zero value in P3. Imagine that for NY PIE the values are "null" and "0" [instead 2 and 1]. In such a case would it be possible to get 0 instead null. In other word, is it possible to ignore nulls in the query ?

Comment: Of course, you can put whatever condition you want in the inner query, just add a `where` clause

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `row_num` window function to order the rows according to their `p3` values and take the first one:

```
SELECT city, prod, p1, p2, p3
FROM   (SELECT city, prod, p1, p2, p3,
               ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY city, prod ORDER BY p3 DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that it works with postgres but for some reason HANA does not support that. I did not mention the database technology because I was assuming the query would be more simple than what I expected. So I think i will accept the solution of Blindy but of course your solution seems to be perfect for other databases.

Comment: Just a note, mine is T-Sql. I don't know what HANA is, but if mine works then it's probably based on Microsoft Sql Server. It most likely won't work on anything else, that CTE expression is Microsoft-specific.